# TSQL CASE WHEN id.id null then '' else '@' end

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

In my select, I'm using a statement like this to add a second cell, if it is not null, and to zero out the cell if it is null.

```
Child.Tag + '@' + ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(50),parent.Tag),'') as 'Location'
```

This returns a location of F123@A123 if there is a parent location.
However if there isn't a parent location, it will return F123@, where I would like it to only return F123.

I have adjusted the select to this:

```
Child.Tag + CASE Parent.Tag when null then '' else '@' end
```

However this still returns F123@ if the parent location is null.

Does anyone know of a way to have it stop returning the '@', and if anyone has an explanation as to why my CASE statement isn't working that would be greatly appreciated as well.

Thank you.

(Other info: I am on SSMS 2008)

Comment: '@' + NULL is NULL ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
Child.Tag + COALECE('@' + Parent.Tag, '')
```

This adds the `'@'` only when there is a value for `Parent.Tag`.

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) for the simple `case` is:

> - Evaluates input_expression, and then in the order specified, evaluates input_expression = when_expression for each WHEN clause.

`NULL` fails the equality test.  This is subtle, but the `COALESCE()` form is easier to read and write anyway.

Answer (score 3):

As Gordon notes, `CASE Parent.Tag when null` never evaluates as true, even when `Parent.Tag` is NULL - however, `CASE when Parent.Tag is null` *will* evaluate as true when `Parent.Tag` is NULL.

So you could have rewritten your existing expression from the CASE *expression* WHEN *value* ... form, to the CASE WHEN *expression-is-true* ... form, like so:

```
Child.Tag + CASE when Parent.Tag is null then '' else '@' end + ...
```